# Setting Activity Indicator to CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to display activity indicator for the initial load time for each collection view cell. I tried placing it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` however, it's getting created 20 pixels above the cell for some reason.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AACollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AACollectionViewCell

    let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)

    activityView.center = cell.theImage.center
    // Also tried
    activityView.center = cell.contentView.center

    activityView.startAnimating()

    return cell
}
```

What is the proper way of handling it?

---

Edit: I also tried this but it's not creating activityIndicator anywhere

```
    let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
    activityView.center = cell.contentView.center
    cell.contentView.addSubview(activityView)
```

Comment: I have 3 cells and I am initialising cells with the NSUserDefaults that I saved on previous session. So the cycle goes like, I use nsuserdefaults data to display on the cells first, while waiting for the fetching/loading time (of images). Then, when fetching completed, I reloadData(). And yes, I use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.. (Edited my question)

Comment: Yes, I just tried `let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
        activityView.center = cell.contentView.center
        cell.contentView.addSubview(activityView)` but it's not getting created anywhere with only these 3 lines. Let me clear that I have a UIImage on the view of the cell. Maybe it's getting created underneath?

Comment: Thanks a lot once again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cell.contentView.center` gives you the frame of `contentView` from its superview's coordinate system. What you should do:

```
activityView.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width / 2, cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Comment: I have a mini problem with hiding the activityView. I display the activity indicator for each cell however, after fetching is completed and `reloadData()` is called, `activityView.stopAnimating()` doesn't work even though it's the same cell with the same `indexPath.row` :/ What might be the reason for that? I also tried to put it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` but no luck` :/

Comment: Because `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called every time a cell needs to be shown. You should have some kind of if statement to check if data is loaded so `startAnimating()` won't be called.

Comment: Actually, I have the if statement called initialLoad.. What I do is, on `initialLoad` (so nsuserdefaults load), start animating the activity indicator, but don't stop it.. Then the database fetch gets completed and the `collectionview.reloadData()` gets called, so it goes into `! initialLoad` clousure.. I tried to stop animating the activity indicator here. Is it not possible? :/